# Ajax button slide down and append data with fadeIn effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have getting some divs by `Ajax` and I want to get this data, append to `div`, slide button "more" to the bottom and `fadeIn` appended data.

I am trying something like this, but it's non working.

```
 $(".more").click(function() {
     $('.more').html('Loading...');
        jQuery.ajax({

            url: "/?p1=default&c1=cmsnotes&a0=0",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {"mode": "getmorenotes","cnt":$(".post").size(),"categorytag":"all"},
            success: function(data) {
               $(data).hide();
               $("#posts").append(data).fadeIn(1000);
               $('.more').html('More <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
       event.preventDefault();
    });
```

How can I show `ajax` data by button slide down and data `fadeIn`?

Comment: Are you appending the data to the body because as of right now all I believe you are hiding some text not an element?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [size()](https://api.jquery.com/size/) is deprecated since 1.8, use property `length` instead.

```
"cnt": $(".post").length
```